# BLE data transfer error check

Tags: transfer, bluetooth-lowenergy, error-checking

I am currently working on a data transfer via BLE and I cannot find anywhere whether I need to implement my own data error check eg. checkSum or if it is already implemented in the BLE protocol. I have spend couple hours on this without a result... Thank you!